# How to increment nested objects with variable names in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So the code I'd 'like' to work is below. I have a variable name as the name of the key of the object unread, which seems to be in the only way of doing this in MongoDB is by creating an object outside and referencing it as the value for $inc. This doesn't seem to work, it does work however if I just have a key partnerId without nesting the object. My question is how do i get it working with nested objects.

Does work:

```
var partnerId = 234567;
var action = {
  unread: {}
};
action[partnerId] = 1;

Threads.update(Session.get('currentChat'), 
{
  $inc: action
}, callback);
```

Does not work, but would like it to work:

```
var partnerId = 234567;
var action = {
  unread: {}
};
action.unread[partnerId] = 1;

Threads.update(Session.get('currentChat'), 
{
  $inc: action
}, callback);
```

I get an error about not being able to increment things that aren't numbers, which I guess is refering to the object within the object.

The schema I have is like this, with 123456 and 234567 as user ids and I just want to increment that number:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  unread: {
    123456: 0,
    234567: 1,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to write this out in a non-dynamic way, you'd do:

```
var id = Session.get('currentChat');
Threads.update(id, {$inc: {'action.unread.234567': 1}});
```

`$inc` needs to take an object with a dynamically created key based on `partnerId` like so:

```
var partnerId = 234567;
var key = 'action.unread.' + partnerId;
var obj = {};
obj[key] = 1;
```

Now `obj` looks like:

```
{'action.unread.234567': 1}
```

So we can plug that into your original code:

```
Threads.update(id, {$inc: obj}, callback);
```

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, what's the difference between the example i had and the example you had? the only difference i see is the syntax of how you generate the key. Why does this not work `action.unread[partnerId] = 1;`?

Comment: `$inc` takes an object whose keys are the fields to be incremented, and whose values are numbers. The field you want to increment is 'action.unread.234567', so it needs to be a string. In your example, `action` was `{unread: {'234567': 1}}`. So using it with `$inc` was like saying: "please increment `unread` by the value `{'234567': 1}`", which doesn't make sense to the database. I hope that helps. :)